# Value error from tf.nn.dynamic_rnn: Dimensions must be equal

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to use the `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`  function of tensorflow to create a RNN but it allows me to set a hidden size for only one of my layers.

Here is my code:

```
    self._Input=tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=(None,self._time_size,self._batch_dim),name='input')
    self._Expected_o=tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=(None,self._time_size,self._cell_output_size),name='Expected_o')
    #creation of the network

    initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1, 1)      
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(self._hidden_size,kernel_initializer=initializer)  
    rnn_cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * self._num_layer) 

    # network
    self._output, out_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=rnn_cells,inputs= self._Input, dtype=tf.float64)
```

Everything works fine as long as I keep my `hidden_size` value as the same as the last dimension of my Input place holder, i.e., `_batch_dim`.

But when it's different, I always get this message of error:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 8 and X for
>   'rnn/while/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell_0/gru_cell/MatMul_2' (op:
>   'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,Y], [X,Y].

where `X` is the value that I put for my `hidden_size + 1` and `Y` the value of `hidden_size*2`. I've tried many value of `hidden_size` and this two numbers, `X` and `Y` appear each time. The message error indicate that the error occur during the calling of `tf.rnn.dynamic_rnn`.

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code from ...

```py
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(self._hidden_size,kernel_initializer=initializer)  
rnn_cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * self._num_layer)
```

to ...

```py
layers = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(self._hidden_size,kernel_initializer=initializer) 
          for _ in self._num_layer]
rnn_cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(layers)
```

... and the deeper GRU layers will be able to adapt to the output from the earlier layers.

Comment: thanks this is the solution but you justa have to add range(self._num_layer) since self._num_layer is a integer in my case

Comment: @yohansebmoc oops, indeed, forgot `range`. Thanks for spotting it